# try parse in linq

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

Hi I have a linq query as below

```
var perChange = (from data in globalDS.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().AsParallel()
              select data.Field<double>("PercentChange")).ToList();
```

Now the dataset globalDS contains null as well as varchar values in them. So there is an obvious type cast error that is generated. Is there a way to try.Parse the value in "Percentage Change" column and select only the valid fields.

Comment: Why do you have non-numeric data in a `PercentChange` column?

Comment: @DStanley The dataset is read from an excel which contains values like NaN as well as null values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`DataRow.Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb360891%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) supports nullable types:

```
List<double> result = globalDS.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().AsParallel()
             .Where(r  => r.Field<double?>("PercentChange").HasValue)
             .Select(r => r.Field<double?>("PercentChange").Value)
             .ToList();
```

**Edit**: Since you have mentioned that the field contains strings instead of doubles:

```
List<double> result = globalDS.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().AsParallel()
             .Select(r => r.Field<string>("PercentChange").TryGetDouble())
             .Where(nullDouble => nullDouble.HasValue)
             .Select(nullDouble => nullDouble.Value)
             .ToList();
```

I've used this extension to try-parse a string to `double?` which is safer than parsing "on the fly" into the local variable, especially with `AsParallel`:

```
public static Double? TryGetDouble(this string item, IFormatProvider formatProvider = null)
{
    if (formatProvider == null) formatProvider = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
    Double d = 0d;
    bool success = Double.TryParse(item, NumberStyles.Any, formatProvider, out d);
    if (success)
        return d;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Comment: The OP says that the colun contains varchar values... Wouldn't that mean that `r.field<double?>` could fail with an `InvalidCastException`?

Comment: Your 2nd code wont work with the ``.AsParallel()`` the OP used, the value of ``d`` will get unpredictable. If someone coming here needs to work with ``.AsParallel()`` look at @DStanley's answer

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
double temp;

var perChange = (
     from data in globalDS.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().AsParallel()
     where !data.IsNull("PercentChange")
         && double.TryParse(data.Field<string>("PercentChange"), out temp)
     select double.Parse(data.Field<string>("PercentChange"))
    ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a select using a where clause in which you check the type. This would be something like: `where x != null && TypeOf(x) == double`